# BIOS provide incorrect CPU tempatures?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, bios, overheating

I recently built a new AMD computer. The computer runs great (so I think). I have an after market fan on the processor. I installed a program called Core Temp to monitor CPU usage and temperature. The program, I believe, gets the data from the bios. I know for a fact that the temperature I am receiving are incorrect. Today I sat down and noticed that for some reason my cores were all at max power (not really sure why) the temperature was at 35 degrees C for all the cores. I have NEVER seen the temp go above that. When ever a core is maxed it goes to 35 and stops. If nothing is being processed at all they stay at 11 degrees C and average is in the 20s. I am wondering if this board has some kind of malfunction or issues, or maybe I am just a moron?

P.S. I have also tried several other programs, other then core temp all have the same result, so I think the motherboard has some issues or something

P.S.S. When I go into the bios the bios say the CPU is 33 degrees C... every time.

Please let me know what I should do.. It is making me a little worried.

**OS:**

- Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Full (64-bit)

**Parts:**

- AMD FX-8350 4.0GHz 8-Core
- Asus Crosshair V Formula-Z ATX AM3+ Zalman
- CNPS9900ALED Ball Bearing G.Skill Ripjaws Z Series 32GB (4 x 8GB)
- DDR3-1600 Gigabyte GeForce GTX 650 2GB
- Azza Solano 1000R ATX Full
- Tower Corsair 750W ATX12V / EPS12V

Comment: Was your room temperature around 11C when you saw the 11C reading? Your question really doesn't explain what you think the problem is. Do you think those temps are too low? Too high? Not responding to load as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

It's not unheard of for the temperature sensors to be wrong (read: broken). To have your CPU temperature at 11 C is, well, hardly believable.

How recently did you update your BIOS drivers? (I'm assuming quite recently, if you just built your computer)

Is it possible to decrease the speed of the CPU fan, to see if it rises above 35ºC that way? 
If it doesn't, it's quite safe to say the sensor is broken and a replacement is in order.